# Sending custom email with ajax - woocommerce / wordpress user signup

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, email, woocommerce

I'm currently building a custom login / sign up form that either logs the user in, or signs the user up using ajax. I'm able to log users in, and I'm also able to create users, however, i'm having an issue with sending an activation email after a user has signed up.

My intentions are to send out an "account activation" email to new users on sign up. This email would contain a link to a certain page on my site, which if accessed would run code to update the custom user meta 'is_activated' from 0 to 1, to indicate that the user has verified their email.

A new user is being create using the following code. This is called from my ajax script.

```
function ajax_create_new_user () {
    $new_account_username = stripcslashes($_POST['new_account_username']);
    $new_account_email = strtolower(stripcslashes($_POST['new_account_email']));
    $new_account_password = $_POST['new_account_password'];
    $new_account_first_name = $_POST['new_account_first_name'];
    $new_account_last_name = $_POST['new_account_last_name'];

    $user_id = wp_create_user( $new_account_username, $new_account_password, $new_account_email );

    if ( is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
        echo json_encode( $user_id->get_error_message() );
        die();
    }

    wp_update_user(
        array(
            'ID' => $user_id,
            'role' => 'customer',
            'display_name' => $new_account_first_name . " " . $new_account_last_name
            )
    );

    $data = array(
                  'first_name'            => $new_account_first_name,
                  'last_name'             => $new_account_last_name,
                  'billing_first_name'    => $new_account_first_name,
                  'billing_last_name'     => $new_account_last_name
                  );
    foreach ($data as $meta_key => $meta_value ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, $meta_value );
    }
```

I am then automatically logging the user in, using the following:

```
 $creds = array(
                'user_login'    => $new_account_username,
                'user_password' => $new_account_password,
                'remember'      => false,
                   );

    $user_login = wp_signon($creds, false);

    if ( is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
        echo json_encode( $user->get_error_message() );
        die();
    }
```

After this, i'm trying to build up the code to send an email to the user.
So far, I've found and used the **wp_mail()** function. Th function is working, and i'm able to send the new user an email.

```
$code = md5(time());
    $security_string = array('id' => $user_id, 'securitycode' => $code );

    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'is_activated', 0);
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'activation_code', $code);
    $url = get_site_url(). '/verify/?p=' .base64_encode( serialize($security_string));
    $html = ( 'Please click <a href="'.$url.'">here</a> to verify your email address.' );

    wp_mail( $new_account_email, 'Activate your Account', $html);
```

Unfortunately, i'm unsure how to approach building a custom email template (HTML & plain text format) that would be called and populated by my code.

I've found this article (**[click here](https://www.skyverge.com/blog/how-to-add-a-custom-woocommerce-email/)**) that shows how to create a custom WooCommerce email, however how would i be able to pass the new users information (email, security url etc) to this email, so it is populated and sent?

Any information would be useful, thank you!

Josh